# How to forbidden wordpress url exchange `&` to `#038;`?

Tags: wordpress, symbols

I want to pass some value through url in wordpress, but I met some trouble that wordpress will exchange `&` to `#038;` automatically, how to make a `&` still as a `&` ?

I noticed in `wp-includes/formatting.php`, there has many rules to exchange symbols, I tried modify some code, but failed.

some link like

`site.com?this=that&that=this` will output to the web browser address like `site.com?this=that#038that=this`

and the page can not get the value in the part `that=this`

how to setting correctly? thanks.

Comment: Are you inserting those url and their parameters in the post editor through the link insertion tool?

Comment: @AJweb, i insert these url and their parameters in the `page editor`, some code in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable [wptexturize()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) by adding this in a *functions.php* file inside your template folder (or add it to the existing one):

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

But note that this will of course disable all the "cleaning", not just the '&' conversion.

If you prefer to just get rid of the ampersand conversion you can comment line 962 in formatting.php. I post lines 961 and 962 bellow (this is from an unaltered WP 3.1):

```
// Converts lone & characters into &#38; (a.k.a. &amp;)  
$content = preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-z1-4]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;$1', $content);
```

Comment: add  more: also should comment in `formatting.php` `//$curl = preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-zA-Z1-4]{1,8};)/', '&#038;$1', $curl);` and `//$url = str_replace( '&amp;', '&#038;', $url );`.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, after some research I found [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-format/) which fixes it. After installing the plugin you just add these tags around the piece of code you don't want wordpress to format. Like so:

```
<!-- noformat on -->
Your code with & in it
<!-- noformat off -->
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

One More Solution:

`wp-includes\formatting.php`: in `esc_url ()` **comment the line**

```
$url = str_replace( '&', '&', $url );
```

It works for me.

Comment: Use esc_url_raw() which changes the esc_url() context from 'display' to 'db'.   This will no longer swap out the &.

Comment: You should never modify WP core files... Your changes will be lost after update and they may break everything...