# Getting GET variables of a urlencoded url

Tags: php

I have a file referenced in my page like:

```
http://example.com/file.php?first=bob&second=mary&third=tom
```

The URL is being encoded to look like this:

```
http://example.com/file.php?first=bob&#038;second=mary&#038;third=tom
```

Let me now say that I have no control over how this URL is referenced on the page. It will be encoded and I can not change that.

So, in file.php, I have:

```
$first = $_GET['first'];
$second = $_GET['second'];
$third = $_GET['third'];
```

When the page is loaded, I am getting `undefined index` errors for `$second` and `$third`.

How can I get my page to pick up what these GET variables are if the URL is encoded like this?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the URL parsing standards says that the query part ends when finding # so what's after # is a fragment it's not available to PHP AFAIK so no work around.

If this is related to wordpress check [How to forbidden wordpress url exchange `&` to `#038;`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605122/how-to-forbidden-wordpress-url-exchange-to-038)

Comment: This is correct - once that query string hits PHP its query string is truncated to the first value only. You can parse the URL manually if you have it in a string, but since it gets cut down before it gets to either $_GET or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'] etc, it's a no go. You could however use Javascript to get the query string and parse it that way - the ramifications of this are that you'd need to perform your PHP requests using these variables with AJAX instead of server-side